# Naming output same as input in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model which has 6 select queries for different feet of contours.

I want to be able to give the same name as the input town/city for the output.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Parse Path](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path.htm) in the [model only tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-model-only-tools.htm) to get the `File Name` as a variable, and then use it as a %variable% in the output file name.

Comment: Where can I find the 'Parse Path' tool in ArcMap? @HDunn

Comment: @PowerToYou in the Model Only tools tab. 
 http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-model-only-tools.htm

Comment: Is there a way I can change the name every time i.e. just the number towards the end of the name?? @HDunn

Comment: I can only use parse path for the first select process. Other processes, if connected, throw an error. @HDunn

Comment: I got the model to work using the 'Parse Path' and user inputting the name of the feature class ahead of the path.